# Oracle regex for all characters before a specific string

Tags: sql, regex, oracle

I'm working on a substring regular expression and I need to get all characters from a string like this:

FIRSTCOLUMN, SECONDCOLUMN, THIRDCOLUMN

So far I've got:

```
SELECT 
    REGEXP_SUBSTR('FIRSTCOLUMN, SECONDCOLUMN, THIRDCOLUMN', '[^SECONDCOLUMN]+') AS SUBSTRING 
FROM DUAL;
```

This returns just "FIR" but I need the result to be "FIRSTCOLUMN, ".

Another example to understand better the question is:
when I have `'[^THIRDCOLUMN]+'` pattern instead of `'[^SECONDCOLUMN]+'` as the first example, I want the result to be "FIRSTCOLUMN, SECONDCOLUMN, ".

I know it is possible but I'm not good enough on regular expressions.

Answer (score 2):

You are getting basic regular expressions concepts wrong. The `[^...]` negates all *characters* inside the class, so it looks for characters not `S`, not `E`, not `C`, etc which correctly stops at FIR**S**T (see the `S`).
What you possibly want is a lazy quantifier:

```
^.*?SECONDCOLUMN
```

or

```
^.*?THIRDCOLUMN
```

respectively.

Comment: Technically, you need some syntactic sugar to exclude the delimiting string from being part of the result: either wrap it with a `replace(..., 'secondcolumn')` or use  `select regexp_substr ( 'firstcolumn, secondcolumn, thirdcolumn', '^(.*?)secondcolumn', 1, 1, null, 1 ) from dual;` The additional arguments denote match offset, occurrence, match parameters, capture group to be returned (oracle 12c only). Consult oracle docs for detailed info. If any term is double dutch to you, consider to take a tour to a site explaining regexen (eg. http://www.regular-expressions.info/).

Comment: @Jan Thanks for the suggestion. But I wanted to exclude the SECONDCOLUMN string of the first example. So, using your suggestion, my code became:

**_SELECT 
    REGEXP_SUBSTR('FIRSTCOLUMN, SECONDCOLUMN, THIRDCOLUMN', '^.*?SECONDCOLUMN') AS SUBSTRING 
FROM DUAL;_**

But my result is: **FIRSTCOLUMN, SECONDCOLUMN**

In my case I wanted the result to be: **FIRSTCOLUMN, **
That's why I put the '[^...]', to exculde "SECONDCOLUMN" from "FIRSTCOLUMN, **SECONDCOLUMN**" .

Thank you in advice.